# Jenkins parameter cannot be recognized in command line

Tags: node.js, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a simple job using NodeJS, Github and Jenkins. 
There are an exchange what runs on two servers addresses: 
for example, us.exchange.com and eu.exchange.com.
I created an environment variable named SERVERS_LOCATION,

`` browser.get(`http://${process.env.SERVERS_LOCATION}.exchange.com`); ``

and a Jenkins parameter named SERVERS_LOCATION_JEN which may takes two options - US and EU.

Also I created a pipeline in Jenkins where I want to run parameterized build by choose one or another option, for that I use pipeline script in *jenkinsfile* what looks like that:

```
pipeline{
    agent any    
    options{
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages{
        stage("install npm"){
            steps{                
                bat "npm install"                
                bat "npx webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 76.0.3809.68"                
            }            
        }

        stage("executing job"){
            steps{
                bat "SERVERS_LOCATION=%SERVERS_LOCATION_JEN% npx protractor config/conf.js"                           
            }            
        }
    }    
}
```

The main idea is to take the choosen value from Jenkins variable SERVERS_LOCATION_JEN and put it to environment variable ${process.env.SERVERS_LOCATION}, which can be used in code for further calls.

But when I running this job I have an error:

```
'SERVERS_LOCATION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

P.S. running that job from git-bash works fine. (Win10 Chrome browser)

Could you point me please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you not define parameter block and pass this variable from the jenkins job ? If yes you can do something like `parameters {
        choice(choices: 'eu\nus', description: 'The environment to deploy to', name: 'environment')
    }` and then use it like `${params.environment}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "**set**" command to assign a value to a variable in batch, so please use the below code:-

```
bat "set SERVERS_LOCATION=%SERVERS_LOCATION_JEN% npx protractor config/conf.js"
```

Comment: can please also rate the answer, Thank You!